# Salvar filtro realizado no tablesorter

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um sistema que retorna os clientes cadastrados com tablesorter, porem quando edito um usuário e volto a tela, o filtro realizado para achar um determinado grupo de clientes muda, existe alguma maneira de salvar este filtro ao retornar a listagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver utilizando uma versão do tablesorter maior ou igual que a 2.9 você pode guardar o filtro no local storage do navegador, então quando a página for recarregada, os registros continuam na mesma ordem. O construtor ficaria da seguinte forma:

```js
$(function() {

  // call the tablesorter plugin
  $("table").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',

    // use save sort widget
    widgets: ["saveSort", "zebra"],
    widgetOptions: {
      // enable/disable saveSort dynamically
      saveSort: true
    }

  });
});
```

Aqui tem um exemplo:

https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html
https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/